# How to save a mix of strings and numbers into text files in specified format using numpy.savetxt?

Tags: python, numpy

with one array of strings and the other array of numbers, like

```
str_arr = np.array(['object1_short', 'object2_intermidiate', 'object3_long'])
```

and

```
flt_arr = np.array([10.01234235, 11.01234235, 12.023432])
```

How can I specified `fmt` in `np.savetxt` so that the text file will be

```
object1    10.01
object2    11.01
object3    12.02
```

, i.e., two arrays in `%7s` and `%4.2f` respectively.

I really want to use `numpy.savetxt` to do this, but directly specifying

```
np.savetxt("output.txt", np.vstack([str_arr, flt_arr]).T), fmt = '%7s %4.2f')
```

seems doesnot work. Is it doable with `savetxt` at all? I really prefer a `numpy.array` based solution rather than going for spliting and reformating using list comprehensions, or recarrays.

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with structured/record arrays?

Comment: @MichaelHoffman just because there are many such ndarrays created in the current code (not mine), and the orginal code directly dump the vstacked content to output without formatting, so I want to know if there is a straightforward way to format them without much refactoring the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make an `ndarray` of nonhomogeneous array types, so stacking `str_arr` and `flt_arr` won't work. You could start by converting `flt_arr` into an array of `str`s doing something like this:

```
>>> np.char.mod("%4.2f", flt_arr)
array(['10.01', '11.01', '12.02'], 
      dtype='|S5')
```

Comment: Yup, this is what I am using right now, maybe the closest I can get without refactoring the current code.

Comment: Nice, this is pretty close to what the asker wants, I wasn't thinking hard enough.  I suppose you could explicitly do the formatting ahead of time, `f42_arr = np.array(['%4.2f' % x for x in flt_arr])` though this is edging toward what the asker doesn't want, "reformating using list comprehensions."

Comment: Looks like you can do that after all with `numpy.char.mod()` so I've edited my answer to change from `astype()` to reflect that.